# Minecraft random wildfires

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I was playing Minecraft, and a random wildfire occurred near my house suddenly. I managed to put it out, but then a second one occurred a fair way off, I managed to put that one out, but then next thing I know, another fire started on my house! I didn't manage to put that one out in time, and my whole house burned down.

Can someone tell me why or how this happened?

Comment: Unfortunately with the amount of detail you've given us, it's unlikely we'll be able to give you an answer. Are you playing with other people? What was the weather doing? Was there a thunderstorm happening at the time?

Comment: Do you hear the sound of bubbling lava? Could be a pocket juuust under the surface. If you built a fireplace in your house, how close were any flammable blocks (wood, wool, etc) to it?

Comment: Voted to reopen. Just because there are lots of possibilities doesn't mean we can't make an answer out of them.

Answer (score 2):

There are many random lava falls that usually generate in the grassland biomes. Wood, wool and leaves are more likely to catch on fire than any other block. If it was inside of your house lava may be right under your home. There also is a high chance for a mine to be under there too. When building a house I highly recommend not building on top of a lava pit!